# Question regarding random variable in product probability space

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I am struggling at solving product probability space questions, I am wondering if anyone could me with the following question. Let $x_{i}$ be a random variable at probability space ($X_{i}$, $\Sigma_{i}$, $P_{i}$), where i = 1,2. Now define a f such that f($w_{1}$, $w_{2}$) = $x_{1}$($w_{1}$) - $x_{2}$($w_{2}$), for $w_{i}$ $\in$ $\Sigma_{i}$.

The question is to show that if f is almost surely equal to zero, then both $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are almost surely constant functions.

I am starting to first prove that f is in fact a random variable on product space ($X_{1}$   $\times$ $X_{2}$, $\Sigma_{1}$ $\times$ $\Sigma_{2}$), but even it's proved to be a random variable, I still have no clue how to show  $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are almost surely constant functions.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent.